# How can I update nested immutable in reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am pretty new for immutable.js.
I want update `home.filmList[0].isDetailModalShow = false.`
How can i do it?
Please help me!
My state like this:

```js
{
  home: {
    filmList: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: '111',
        imgUrl: '111',
        isDetailModalShow: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: '222',
        imgUrl: '',
        isDetailModalShow: false
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

and my reducer like this

```js
import { createReducer } from 'redux-act'
import { fromJS } from 'immutable'
import { setFilmList, toggleDetailModal } from './actions'

const initialState = fromJS({
  filmList: [],
})

export default createReducer({
  [toggleDetailModal]: (state, payload) => {
    const index = state.get('filmList').findIndex(item => item.id === payload)
    // state.get(filmList) is filmList: [........]
    // below line code do not work!
    return state.updateIn(['filmList', index, 'isDetailModalShow'], value => !value)
  },
}, initialState)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Immutable's [`setIn`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/setIn) function:

`state.setIn(['filmList', 0, 'isDetailModalShow'], false)`

Comment: It alert Uncaught Error: invalid keyPath

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution... 
When I set `filmList` 
I forgot use fromJS

```js
// old
[setFilmList]: (state, payload) => {
  return state.set('filmList', payload)
}
// new, it works!
[setFilmList]: (state, payload) => {
  return state.set('filmList', fromJS(payload))
}
```